# Link can not use in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Error:

> ./node_modules/next/dist/client/link.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'F:/PKH/medproweb-nextjs/node_modules/next/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/slicedToArray' i

[image]

Example code:

```js
const HomePage = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Link href="/test">
                <a> click</a>
            </Link>
            <div
                onClick={() => {
                    Router.push('/test')
                }}
            >
            </div>
            <MeDProHomepage />
        </>
    )
}

export default HomePage
```

I have the error when use link in Next.js, the error is link picture, but when I use `Router.push` it works normally. Can someone help me figure it out?

Comment: Can you add your actual usage code? It's really hard to help you with only the error message. Are you sure you have installed everything too? `npm install`

Comment: i did `npm install` and i have added the example code in my post

Comment: For the future, it's better to add your code directly in the question instead of in a screenshot, since the link may die. Remember SO is a wiki and it may be useful to others in the future.

Did you import `Link`? I don't see the imports in the image. Also make sure to comment our your other component `MedProHomepage` to make sure that's not causing the issue.

Comment: thank for your advice, i imported the link and it's still wrong

Comment: i did `npm install again and it worked normally, thank you very much`

Comment: You're welcome! Since that solves your issue, I added an answer with the solution in case someone lands here. Can you please accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the code can't find your Link. Try running `npm install` and making sure the module is imported correctly.

Comment: One addition to this: If reinstalling (i.e., deleting your lockfile and ```node_modules``` folder and then running ```npm install``` or ```yarn install```) should *not* work, then you can also try to delete the ```.next``` folder (which caches the build). That solved the issue for me.